# IIS stop working randomly with weird error

Tags: iis

My company IIS server stops working randomly and it pops the very weird error message as attached screenshot.

Anybody have experience in this error box?

Thanks

[image: Error in IIS]

Comment: I wish you had provided more details to avoid people making wild guesses.

Comment: When you say "stops working" what do you mean?  Are the services still running or do they fail?  How often does this happen?  Anything in the event logs?  This question is VERY vague...

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using ? What are you doing to obtain this error ?

Comment: I usse IIS 7. That's the all information I can get from this error, Might be I need to get some log in Event Viewer the add something more to the question.